# Disable right click in flash with AS or from browser

Tags: javascript, flash, client, dom-events

My question is simple. I want to disable mouse right click on my FLASH GAMES website, so that players cannot leave my website when right clicking a game and clicking on "ABOUT FLASH PLAYER".
My games are developed using AS3 and FLEX/FLASH .

I am interested in any kind of solutions, so that every player that plays my games cannot right click the game and see the "ABOUT FLASH PLAYER" or at least to prevent him leaving the website when clicking "ABOUT FLASH PLAYER".

I tried to disable rightclick from JS but most likely the code wasn't good.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Flash Player 11 try

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent):void{});
```

More details in [this tutorial](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3253).

Comment: Flash Player 11.2, to be precise, and the function has to have 1 parameter (MouseEvent)

Comment: @rustyx oh yeah! I added the return type, might as well add the parameter :) thanks