# Disable right click in Flash in web browsers

Tags: flash, browser, right-click

How do you disable right clicking inside Flash Player content like FarmVille2? Notably, right clicking anywhere in the browser window does not work, ie. no menu shows up, so it must be JavaScript. Flash/AS3 itself has no means to disable the context menu within Flash Player (can be done in Adobe AIR).

Answer (score 2):

Seems a lot like this question here:
[Disable right click in flash with AS or from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786419/disable-right-click-in-flash-with-as-or-from-browser)

in which case this might work:

```
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK,function():void{});
```